# Highcharts with object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I have a little probleme i have an array like this :

```
{"2017-10-20 17:09:40+CEST": 113, "2017-10-20 14:09:40+CEST": 98, "2017-10-22 13:09:40+CEST": 76, "2017-10-23 04:09:40+CEST": 0, "2017-10-22 15:09:40+CEST": 86, "2017-10-21 08:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 23:09:40+CEST": 78, "2017-10-20 09:09:40+CEST": 4, "2017-10-20 23:09:40+CEST": 2, "2017-10-21 00:09:40+CEST": 23, "2017-10-22 11:09:40+CEST": 40, "2017-10-22 20:09:40+CEST": 96, "2017-10-20 13:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-22 05:09:40+CEST": 28, "2017-10-20 16:09:40+CEST": 111, "2017-10-23 01:09:40+CEST": 51, "2017-10-21 23:09:40+CEST": 71, "2017-10-22 21:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-23 06:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-21 20:09:40+CEST": 95, "2017-10-21 10:09:40+CEST": 8, "2017-10-21 12:09:40+CEST": 51, "2017-10-21 15:09:40+CEST": 89, "2017-10-21 14:09:40+CEST": 83, "2017-10-21 09:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-23 08:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-21 22:09:40+CEST": 103, "2017-10-22 22:09:40+CEST": 80, "2017-10-21 11:09:40+CEST": 26, "2017-10-23 05:09:40+CEST": 0, "2017-10-21 01:09:40+CEST": 23, "2017-10-22 18:09:40+CEST": 100, "2017-10-22 01:09:40+CEST": 48, "2017-10-21 07:09:40+CEST": 4, "2017-10-20 20:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-20 18:09:40+CEST": 108, "2017-10-22 17:09:40+CEST": 98, "2017-10-20 10:09:40+CEST": 20, "2017-10-23 11:09:40+CEST": 29, "2017-10-22 07:09:40+CEST": 24, "2017-10-23 07:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-20 22:09:40+CEST": 2, "2017-10-20 21:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 00:09:40+CEST": 63, "2017-10-22 06:09:40+CEST": 25, "2017-10-21 21:09:40+CEST": 95, "2017-10-20 12:09:40+CEST": 79, "2017-10-23 13:09:40+CEST": 67, "2017-10-23 09:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 12:09:40+CEST": 60, "2017-10-20 19:09:40+CEST": 14, "2017-10-22 16:09:40+CEST": 94, "2017-10-21 16:09:40+CEST": 99, "2017-10-22 09:09:40+CEST": 21, "2017-10-22 19:09:40+CEST": 97, "2017-10-21 19:09:40+CEST": 99, "2017-10-21 03:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-23 15:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-22 02:09:40+CEST": 38, "2017-10-21 05:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-21 06:09:40+CEST": 6, "2017-10-20 11:09:40+CEST": 48, "2017-10-22 10:09:40+CEST": 22, "2017-10-23 10:09:40+CEST": 10, "2017-10-22 03:09:40+CEST": 30, "2017-10-23 16:09:40+CEST": 104, "2017-10-23 00:09:40+CEST": 64, "2017-10-23 12:09:40+CEST": 53, "2017-10-21 13:09:40+CEST": 69, "2017-10-20 15:09:40+CEST": 103, "2017-10-21 02:09:40+CEST": 10, "2017-10-21 17:09:40+CEST": 102, "2017-10-22 04:09:40+CEST": 26, "2017-10-21 04:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-21 18:09:40+CEST": 100, "2017-10-23 02:09:40+CEST": 20, "2017-10-22 14:09:40+CEST": 77, "2017-10-23 03:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-23 14:09:40+CEST": 78, "2017-10-22 08:09:40+CEST": 24}}
```

And i want to use it because i want to create graph with highchart but i have a little probleme ... my value is stock inside an array and this is how i try to use it :

And i must sort by date the value because each time the order of the values is different

```
series: [{
          showInLegend: false,
         data: Object.keys(array_24_h)
       }]
```

but i have nothing on my screen ...
I've never done it (javascript)and I don't know how to do it.
So any help is welcome ! 
Thanks !

EDIT :

This my complete code :

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://pedago.fr/logtimes/',
    success: function(data)
    {
      $('#zone').html("<div id='zone'>"+ data.current+"</div>");
      array_24_h = data.past_day;// the output is above

   $(document).ready(function() {

     chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
       chart: {
         renderTo: 'container', 
         backgroundColor: '#282b31', 
         type: 'line',
         options3d: {
           enabled: true,
           alpha: 45
         }
       },
       colors: ['#c7381f', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF'],
       yAxis: {
         allowDecimals: false,
         title: {
           text: 'users',
         }
       },
       xAxis: {
         showInLegend: false,
         allowDecimals: false,
         title: {
           text: 'minute',
         }

       },

       title: {
         text: '12H',
         style: {
           color: '#878b8f',
           font: 'bold 15px "Raleway", Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
       },
       subtitle: {
         text: ' '
       },
       plotOptions: {
         pie: {
           innerSize: 100,
           depth: 45
         }
       },
       credits: {
         enabled: false
       },
       series: [{
          showInLegend: false,
         name: 'users', 
         data: //no idea
       }]
     });
   });
},
error: function(){$('#zone').html("<div id='zone'> Cette requête AJAX n'a pas abouti </div>");}
  });
```

Comment: Ok but series got a parents and to targetting parent we do magical things? post hierarchical data no cup of code.

Comment: Ok it's Edit :)

Comment: ok i am looking for a solution but from your url ajax i got nothing i will try with your json.

Comment: That's because it's an internal URL :/

Comment: ok pas de problemo ;)

Comment: question tu peux ou pas modifier ton schema, car il n'est pas valide d'un point de vue itérateur?

Comment: Non ... Justement le soucis est la... faut que je demande à celui qui à fait le script si il peut me le rendre plus propre parceque sur ce schema j'en ai aucune idée de comment faire, ca me semble pas trop faisable ...

Comment: En fait il a fait un object literal {"key":"valeur","key":"valeur"} sauf qu'avec ce genre d'object tu ne peux boucler dessus, il aurait fallu `[{}, {}, ...]` pour respecter l'exigence du highchart et surtout ici on peux boucler.

Comment: Re je suis parti mangé bon j'ai trouvé une solution mais pour le reste je te laisse la main.

Comment: Bonne soirée en espérant que cela te convient, j'ai mit le traitement des données dans la function ajax que j'ai commenté volontairement pour le test les datas sont bien formaté pour le system highcharts. A plus.

Answer (score 0):

About the your data i did a little add to transform Object to a array of object based on attributes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var datas = {"2017-10-20 17:09:40+CEST": 113, "2017-10-20 14:09:40+CEST": 98, "2017-10-22 13:09:40+CEST": 76, "2017-10-23 04:09:40+CEST": 0, "2017-10-22 15:09:40+CEST": 86, "2017-10-21 08:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 23:09:40+CEST": 78, "2017-10-20 09:09:40+CEST": 4, "2017-10-20 23:09:40+CEST": 2, "2017-10-21 00:09:40+CEST": 23, "2017-10-22 11:09:40+CEST": 40, "2017-10-22 20:09:40+CEST": 96, "2017-10-20 13:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-22 05:09:40+CEST": 28, "2017-10-20 16:09:40+CEST": 111, "2017-10-23 01:09:40+CEST": 51, "2017-10-21 23:09:40+CEST": 71, "2017-10-22 21:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-23 06:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-21 20:09:40+CEST": 95, "2017-10-21 10:09:40+CEST": 8, "2017-10-21 12:09:40+CEST": 51, "2017-10-21 15:09:40+CEST": 89, "2017-10-21 14:09:40+CEST": 83, "2017-10-21 09:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-23 08:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-21 22:09:40+CEST": 103, "2017-10-22 22:09:40+CEST": 80, "2017-10-21 11:09:40+CEST": 26, "2017-10-23 05:09:40+CEST": 0, "2017-10-21 01:09:40+CEST": 23, "2017-10-22 18:09:40+CEST": 100, "2017-10-22 01:09:40+CEST": 48, "2017-10-21 07:09:40+CEST": 4, "2017-10-20 20:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-20 18:09:40+CEST": 108, "2017-10-22 17:09:40+CEST": 98, "2017-10-20 10:09:40+CEST": 20, "2017-10-23 11:09:40+CEST": 29, "2017-10-22 07:09:40+CEST": 24, "2017-10-23 07:09:40+CEST": 1, "2017-10-20 22:09:40+CEST": 2, "2017-10-20 21:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 00:09:40+CEST": 63, "2017-10-22 06:09:40+CEST": 25, "2017-10-21 21:09:40+CEST": 95, "2017-10-20 12:09:40+CEST": 79, "2017-10-23 13:09:40+CEST": 67, "2017-10-23 09:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-22 12:09:40+CEST": 60, "2017-10-20 19:09:40+CEST": 14, "2017-10-22 16:09:40+CEST": 94, "2017-10-21 16:09:40+CEST": 99, "2017-10-22 09:09:40+CEST": 21, "2017-10-22 19:09:40+CEST": 97, "2017-10-21 19:09:40+CEST": 99, "2017-10-21 03:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-23 15:09:40+CEST": 90, "2017-10-22 02:09:40+CEST": 38, "2017-10-21 05:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-21 06:09:40+CEST": 6, "2017-10-20 11:09:40+CEST": 48, "2017-10-22 10:09:40+CEST": 22, "2017-10-23 10:09:40+CEST": 10, "2017-10-22 03:09:40+CEST": 30, "2017-10-23 16:09:40+CEST": 104, "2017-10-23 00:09:40+CEST": 64, "2017-10-23 12:09:40+CEST": 53, "2017-10-21 13:09:40+CEST": 69, "2017-10-20 15:09:40+CEST": 103, "2017-10-21 02:09:40+CEST": 10, "2017-10-21 17:09:40+CEST": 102, "2017-10-22 04:09:40+CEST": 26, "2017-10-21 04:09:40+CEST": 5, "2017-10-21 18:09:40+CEST": 100, "2017-10-23 02:09:40+CEST": 20, "2017-10-22 14:09:40+CEST": 77, "2017-10-23 03:09:40+CEST": 3, "2017-10-23 14:09:40+CEST": 78, "2017-10-22 08:09:40+CEST": 24};

  var data = [];
Object.keys(datas).forEach(function(key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[key] = datas[key];
  data.push(obj); //push newly created object in `op`array
});
 console.log(data[0]);



/*$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    url: 'http://pedago.fr/logtimes/',
    success: function(datas)
    {
      var data = [];
    Object.keys(datas).forEach(function(key) {
      var obj = {};
      obj[key] = datas[key];
      data.push(obj); //push newly created object in `op`array
    });
    },
    error: function(){$('#zone').html("<div id='zone'> Cette requête AJAX n'a pas abouti </div>");}
    });*/





$('#zone').html("<div id='zone'>"+ data.current+"</div>");
      array_24_h = data.past_day;// the output is above

      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
       chart: {
         renderTo: 'container', 
         backgroundColor: '#282b31', 
         type: 'line',
         options3d: {
           enabled: true,
           alpha: 45
         }
       },
       colors: ['#c7381f', '#0066FF', '#00CCFF'],
       yAxis: {
         allowDecimals: false,
         title: {
           text: 'users',
         }
       },
       xAxis: {
         showInLegend: false,
         allowDecimals: false,
         title: {
           text: 'minute',
         }

       },

       title: {
         text: '12H',
         style: {
           color: '#878b8f',
           font: 'bold 15px "Raleway", Verdana, sans-serif'
         }
       },
       subtitle: {
         text: ' '
       },
       plotOptions: {
         pie: {
           innerSize: 100,
           depth: 45
         }
       },
       credits: {
         enabled: false
       },
       series: [{
          showInLegend: false,
         name: 'users', 
         data: data//no idea
       }]
     });
     //console.log(data)
});
```

https://codepen.io/headmax/pen/VMObbV